# How to retrieve last row from Excel Online in Microsoft Flow?

Tags: excel, power-automate

I am trying to retrieve a new record inserted in Excel Online through Microsoft Flow. The new record is inserted as a last row in the Excel.

Is there a function or expression which I can use in Get Row action of flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take two different approaches:

A)  Use `last(body('List_rows_present_in_a_table'))` in a Compose block
[image]

B) Or even easier, if using advanced options:

[image]